# snowflake python connector throws 403 forbidden after 6 hours

Tags: python, amazon-s3, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, urllib3

I have a piece of code that downloads large amounts of data(>200M) from snowflake and writes it into my local database. I am using `Python Snowflake connector v2.1.3` to pull my data. It runs properly for ~6 hours after which it starts to throw 403 error from snowflake and eventually shuts down. I have tried using the recommended params such as `insecure_mode=True` and `client_session_keep_alive=True`, but nothing work:

```
2021-05-12 09:45:40,061 [INFO/ForkPoolWorker-2/pid(26)][/app/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/ssl_wrap_socket.py:427] THIS CONNECTION IS IN INSECURE MODE. IT MEANS THE CERTIFICATE WILL BE VALIDATED BUT THE CERTIFICATE REVOCATION STATUS WILL NOT BE CHECKED.
2021-05-12 09:45:40,279 [DEBUG/ForkPoolWorker-2/pid(26)][/app/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:393] https://sfc-va-ds1-2-customer-stage.s3.amazonaws.com:443 "GET /9jz1-s-vass3666/results/019c2ffa-0502-21c7-0000-39b10525bbee_0/main/data_0_0_18?x-amz-server-side-encryption-customer-algorithm=AES256&response-content-encoding=gzip&AWSAccessKeyId=<key_id>&Expires=1620808614&Signature=<signature> HTTP/1.1" 403 None
2021-05-12 09:45:40,280 [DEBUG/ForkPoolWorker-2/pid(26)][/app/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/network.py:822] HTTP 403: Forbidden. Retrying...
2021-05-12 09:45:40,281 [ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-2/pid(26)][/app/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/network.py:678] HTTP 403: Forbidden
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/network.py", line 652, in _request_exec_wrapper
    **kwargs)
  File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/network.py", line 913, in _request_exec
    raise err
  File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/network.py", line 824, in _request_exec
    raise RetryRequest(exi)
snowflake.connector.network.RetryRequest: HTTP 403: Forbidden
2021-05-12 09:45:40,282 [DEBUG/ForkPoolWorker-2/pid(26)][/app/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/network.py:953] Active requests sessions: 1, idle: 3
2021-05-12 09:45:40,282 [ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-2/pid(26)][/app/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/chunk_downloader.py:148] Failed to fetch the large result set chunk 18/2035
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/network.py", line 652, in _request_exec_wrapper
    **kwargs)
  File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/network.py", line 913, in _request_exec
    raise err
  File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/network.py", line 824, in _request_exec
    raise RetryRequest(exi)
snowflake.connector.network.RetryRequest: HTTP 403: Forbidden

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/chunk_downloader.py", line 125, in _download_chunk
    result_data = self._fetch_chunk(self._chunks[idx].url, headers)
  File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/chunk_downloader.py", line 258, in _fetch_chunk
    binary_data_handler=handler)
  File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/network.py", line 612, in fetch
    **kwargs)
  File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/network.py", line 692, in _request_exec_wrapper
    Error.errorhandler_wrapper(conn, None, cause)
  File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/errors.py", line 100, in errorhandler_wrapper
    connection.errorhandler(connection, cursor, errorclass, errorvalue)
  File "/app/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/errors.py", line 73, in default_errorhandler
    done_format_msg=errorvalue.get(u'done_format_msg'))
snowflake.connector.errors.ForbiddenError: HTTP 403: Forbidden
```

and all that you know after this is

```
2021-05-12 09:45:46,405 [DEBUG/ForkPoolWorker-2/pid(26)][/app/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:393] https://sfc-va-ds1-2-customer-stage.s3.amazonaws.com:443 "GET /9jz1-s-vass3666/results/019c2ffa-0502-21c7-0000-39b10525bbee_0/main/data_0_0_19?x-amz-server-side-encryption-customer-algorithm=AES256&response-content-encoding=gzip&AWSAccessKeyId=<key>&Expires=1620808614&Signature=<signature> HTTP/1.1" 403 None
2021-05-12 09:45:46,406 [DEBUG/ForkPoolWorker-2/pid(26)][/app/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/network.py:822] HTTP 403: Forbidden. Retrying...
2021-05-12 09:45:46,407 [DEBUG/ForkPoolWorker-2/pid(26)][/app/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/network.py:706] retrying: errorclass=<class 'snowflake.connector.errors.ForbiddenError'>, error=HTTP 403: Forbidden, counter=136, sleeping=16(s)
```

it looks to me that the connection to snowflake is active but the connection to the stage is expired, is there any way that I can solve this ?

Comment: How are you setting the `client_session_keep_alive`? through SQL or via the python client?

Comment: Increasing the number of prefetch threads will help, but client app will need more memory. We use by default 4 threads, double it and it should help, see [client_prefetch_threads](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-api.html#connect)

Comment: @SimonDarr, using the python client. 

Also, Sergiu, I have 800M records actually, so even with triple the number of threads, would take more. So I would like to resolve the issue.

Comment: Are you running your code remotely? I am having the same exact issue where query result chunks that are written to an S3 bucket (like `sfc-va-ds1-2-customer-stage`) cannot be not be fetched by the python connector due to 403. Running my code on my local machine works well (no 403s), but I run into the problem when I run the same code deployed to a Fargate instance using the same exact connection parameters (credentials and all).

Comment: @Marconius, in my case, it happens in all the scenarios. The issue here is that AWS  s3 resigned URL expires after 6hours and that's the reason, I am able to get the data for 6hours before the s3 returns 403.

Comment: I have this same 403 issue when `fetchmany`ing 10,000 results at a time (generator) which parameterize Google Maps API calls (c. 45/second). I too hit a 403 after 6 hours of fetching results (or c. 970,000 results)...but I'm not using s3 anywhere. Will try again shortly, but I suspect there is _some_ issue with the Snowflake connection...

Comment: @Per48edjes, you directly aren't using s3. Snowflake internally uses s3 stage. Behind the scenes, when you run a query, the results when fetched in batches, the first resultset comes from snowflake directly and this first resultset, the s3 url would ideally be present (s3 presigned URL), you connector then will fetch results from this s3 instead of snowflake.

Comment: @Per48edjes : Were you able to find the solution for the issue. I am encountering the exact same issue. and i am using EC2 for data processing in chunk of 5000 results at a time. No S3 involved. How did you manage to solve the error? Please suggest. I have also posted the question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71579371/snowflake-error-http-403-forbidden-after-8-hrs-of-processing-data

Comment: @Akshay, not sure if it applies to everyone, but in our case we needed to allow access to the a vpcendpoint for the s3 bucket where the staged result files are kept by snowflake. If you run `SELECT SYSTEM$WHITELIST()`, snowflake will provide you all the routes that need to be made accessible to your snowflake connector. The ones that are of `"type":"STAGE"` are for s3.

Answer (score 1):

When a query is executed, the result is persisted (i.e. cached) for a period of time. At the end of the time period, the result is purged from the system.

Snowflake uses persisted query results to avoid re-generating results when nothing has changed (i.e. “retrieval optimization”). In addition, you can use persisted query results to post-process the results (e.g. layering a new query on top of the results already calculated).

For persisted query results of all sizes, the cache expires after 24 hours.

Note that the security token used to access **large** persisted query results (i.e. greater than 100 KB in size) expires after **6 hours**. A new token can be retrieved to access results while they are still in cache. Smaller persisted query results do not use an access token.

As an exception Snowflake support team can increase for you the security token validity but only temporarily.

The information is also documented on our public docs [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-persisted-results).

Comment: How to retrieve a new token? The public docs say that "a new token can be retrieved to access results" but don't say how.