# Snowflake throws 403 Forbidden when consuming large result set from Python generator after c. 6 hours

Tags: python, generator, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a query that returns millions of results, but I do not want to store the entire result set in memory, so I am using the following code to retrieve records in batches:

```py
def batch_query_results(sql_filename: str, num_rows: int) -> list[tuple]:
    """
    Executes arbitrary query from SQL file and returns results as a batch-result
    generator
    """
    with get_connection() as conn:
        with open(sql_filename, "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
            query = f.read()
            cur = conn.cursor().execute(query)
            logger.info("Executed Snowflake query!")
            unfetched_results = True
            while unfetched_results:
                results = cur.fetchmany(num_rows)
                if len(results) > 0:
                    logger.info(f"Fetched {len(results)} rows from query results...")
                    yield results
                else:
                    unfetched_results = False
```

When I set `num_row = 10_000`, this works pretty well until about the time I get to 980001st record (so c. 98th call to the generator to yield the next batch) which is about 6 hours after the start of execution since I'm rate limited by the API that consumes each result.

Then I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/.../lib/python3.9/site-packages/snowflake/connector/result_batch.py", line 315, in _download
    raise RetryRequest(error)
snowflake.connector.network.RetryRequest: 000403: 403: HTTP 403: Forbidden
```

This happens like clockwork. I took a look at the [source code](https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-python/blob/6b4fbceb6a9773e44348b6d759a3320922979598/src/snowflake/connector/result_batch.py#L207) and I noticed this docstring:

```py
class ResultBatch(abc.ABC):
    """Represents what the back-end calls a result chunk.

    These are parts of a result set of a query. They each know how to retrieve their
    own results and convert them into Python native formats.

    As you are iterating through a ResultBatch you should check whether the yielded
    value is an ``Exception`` in case there was some error parsing the current row
    we might yield one of these to allow iteration to continue instead of raising the
    ``Exception`` when it occurs.

    These objects are pickleable for easy distribution and replication.

    Please note that the URLs stored in these do expire. The lifetime is dictated by the
    Snowflake back-end, at the time of writing this this is 6 hours.

    They can be iterated over multiple times and in different ways. Please follow the
    code in ``cursor.py`` to make sure that you are using this class correctly.
    """
```

Is this the reason why I am getting this error? If so, how might I work around this other than just chunking my work into 980000 row increments?

---

{ **Note**: This is similar, but not quite the same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67502234/snowflake-python-connector-throws-403-forbidden-after-6-hours) unanswered question. }

Comment: Would it be an option to write the result set into a file in a `stage` and use `get` command to download it? Would be more efficient and whole lot faster.

Comment: For large result set operations, each chunk (data that needs to be downloaded) has a unique **token** generated by Snowflake that is specific to the Cloud Provider where the account is and has a default lifetime of 6 hours. If you need this to be longer (taking into account the potential security impact of tokens valid for a longer period of time) you can open a case and ask Snowflake support to increase the lifetime.

Comment: Thanks for the help, y'all. @demircioglu, that's an interesting idea -- would that be faster if I'm immediately using the results (from the chunk) to parameterize an [entirely different] API call to another service? (In my mind: query, fetch, write to disk, read from disk, make call, cache result seems more _inefficient_ than query, fetch, make call, cache result, [rinse, repeat]) Definitely do let me know if I'm fundamentally misunderstanding something!